# No mapping exists from object type Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-6.0, spatial

I'm receiving the following error when storing data with DbGeography type in the database, using Entity Framework 6.4.4 and .NET 6:

No mapping exists from object type Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography to a known managed provider native type.

Using the latest version of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types: 160.1000.6.

Stacktrace:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: No mapping exists from object type Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography to a known managed provider native type.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.MetaType.GetMetaTypeFromValue(Type dataType, Object value, Boolean inferLen, Boolean streamAllowed)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.MetaType.GetMetaTypeFromType(Type dataType)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetMetaTypeOnly()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.get_SqlDbType()
```

The error occurs when saving data to the database. (EF SaveChanges())

Comment: Maybe try my alternativ provider: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer

Comment: @ErikEJ That works indeed, great job! Do you think that this will also work in the upcoming EF 6.5 when your pull request (https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/pull/2063) is merged?

Comment: I will yes, my PR is based on the exact same concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my alternative provider, same concept will also apply to the upcoming EF 6.5 provider - Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer